# Socket.io multiroom chat examples, ready for production

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have written a small site where the main focus is users can create chatrooms for themselves. I've used [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) and wrote everything myself, trying to get something working.

The site is now out and it turns out my solutions are horribly unreliable. Users complain about messages swallowed, sudden disconnects without notification, some users are logged in 6 times in the same chat, etc etc.

Maybe someone has some example software, open source, that implements a multiroom chat with `node.js` and `socket.io` that is ready for production.

I also begin to think that `forever start` is maybe not the intended way to have a `node.js` server running.

Comment: Could you post your findings, as to what the root-cause was for the problems experienced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[node-simple-chat](https://github.com/jmg/node-simple-chat) is a node.js / socket.io realtime chat.

Or check out [Now.js](http://nowjs.com/guide), it also has a guide/example for a chat.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the available chat source code: http://chat.nodejs.org/ ? 
Good place to start.

One of node.js' primary examples is a chat functionality.
You may also check out the modules on github: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

There are quite a few frameworks already built for chatrooms.

Comment: Links seem dead by now

Answer (score 0):

Here you may find a tutorial and sample code to start with - http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2012/11/how-to-develop-highload-services-on-node-js/?lang=en

We used socket.io in one project and ended up with custom transport implementation due to some socket.io bugs (sockets management & poor Internet handling).